# screen detach event handling for 2 in 1 device in universal app?

Tags: windows, windows-8, win-universal-app

Is there any event for screen detachment for 2 in 1 device ?
i mean if i remove the screen from keyboard panel there should be a event handling and when re assemble one more event .

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at `SizeChanged` and then check `UIViewSettings.GetForCurrentView().UserInteractionMode` as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn917883(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: sizeChanged event works only if the size of the window change , i want something if i detach  the screen from keyboard surface while running the app one event should occur depend on which i ll be dong some changes in UI of my application . could u help me in that ?

Comment: i am working on windows 8 not win10 so UIViewSettings does not work in that

Comment: Sorry, not really, though that article I linked might have some clues. You should probably respond to interaction methods more than accessories being attached or not.